# Excel to Word VBA. Create Hover Texts for 25k Definitions

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, bookmarks

### What is the BEST option to create Hover Texts for 25k Definitions?

###### (Excel to Word using VBA)

---

- **Screen Tips?**
- **Tool Tips?**
- **Foot Notes?**
- **Glossary?**
- **Book Marks?**
- **Other Options?**

*Over 25K Definitions in Table*

---

> **Based on feedback and countless HOURS, Im having a tough time figuring out the best option for a Text Hover Effect.**

> **Ive tried Bookmarks and Screen Tips and ran into many issues.**

> **Ive also attempted to tweak the below VBA code to work with Hyperlinks to no avail.**

---

## 3 STEPS

---

1. ### Select the Term from Column:A

---

2. ### Find the Term in Word Document

---

3. ### ADD Definition From Column:B as a HOVER effect in Word

---

```
| Column A    | Column B                 |

| ----------- | ------------------------ |

| Example A   | Definition Example....   |

| Example B   | Definition Example....   |
```

- **Column: A1:A25000 = Term**
- **Column: B1:B25000 = Definition**

---

###### *The below code works great for finding and highlighting the *Terms, But I haven't figured out the Hover Effect.*

---

> #### Favor 2023

```
`'Version #1: Only loops through Word Document Content for text to Find and Replace.
'Leverage & Lean "Less Clicks, More Results"
Sub FindReplaceAcrossMultipleWordDocumentsFreeMacro()
    ' Means variable is in use
    Dim FindReplaceCounter As Integer '
    Dim FolderPath As String '
    Dim LastRow As Integer '
    Dim LastRowPath As Integer '
    Dim MyRange As Object '
    Dim oFile As Object '
    Dim oFolder As Object '
    Dim oFSO As Object '
    Dim WordApp As New Word.Application '
    Dim WordCounter As Integer '
    Dim WordDocument As Object '
   
    On Error GoTo LeverageLean
 
    Set WordApp = New Word.Application 'Forces a New Word Application each and every time.  (Prevents Error 462)
 
    If Cells(2, 3).Value <> "" Then 'If a path to Word Documents exist
        WordCounter = 2
        LastRowPath = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row 'Identify Last Row in Column C
        Do Until WordCounter > LastRowPath 'Loop through any Word Documents in Column C
            Set WordDocument = WordApp.Documents.Open(Cells(WordCounter, 3).Value)
            WordApp.Visible = True
            FindReplaceCounter = 2
            LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Identify Last Row in Column A
            Do Until FindReplaceCounter > LastRow 'Complete the Find and Replace for all values in Column A & B
                Set MyRange = WordApp.ActiveDocument.Content
                With MyRange.Find
                    .Format = True
                    .MatchWholeWord = True
                    '.MatchWildcards = True 'Find and Replace Uppercase & Lowercase Text
                    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                    .Forward = True
                    .Text = Cells(FindReplaceCounter, 1).Value
                    '.Replacement.Highlight = True 'Highlight the Replacement Text Found
                    .Replacement.Text = Cells(FindReplaceCounter, 2).Value
                    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                End With
                FindReplaceCounter = FindReplaceCounter + 1
            Loop
            WordApp.ActiveDocument.Save
            WordApp.ActiveDocument.Close 'Close Active Word Document
            WordCounter = WordCounter + 1
        Loop
    ElseIf Cells(2, 3).Value = "" Then 'If NO paths to Word Documents exist
        FolderPath = Left(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, Len(ActiveWorkbook.FullName) - Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name)) 'Active Workbook File Path
        Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)
        For Each oFile In oFolder.Files 'Loop through every File in Active Workbook's folder path
            If InStr(1, oFile.Type, "Microsoft Word") <> 0 And InStr(1, oFile.Name, "~") = 0 Then 'If the File Type contains the phrase Microsoft Word and is NOT Lock File
                Set WordDocument = WordApp.Documents.Open(FolderPath & oFile.Name)
                WordApp.Visible = True
                FindReplaceCounter = 2
                LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Identify Last Row in Column A
                Do Until FindReplaceCounter > LastRow 'Complete the Find and Replace for all values in Column A & B
                    Set MyRange = WordApp.ActiveDocument.Content
                    With MyRange.Find
                        .Format = True
                        .MatchWholeWord = True
                        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                        .Forward = True
                        .Text = Cells(FindReplaceCounter, 1).Value
                        '.Replacement.Highlight = True 'Highlight the Replacement Text Found
                        .Replacement.Text = Cells(FindReplaceCounter, 2).Value
                        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                    End With
                    FindReplaceCounter = FindReplaceCounter + 1
                Loop
                WordApp.ActiveDocument.Save
                WordApp.ActiveDocument.Close 'Close Active Word Document
            End If
        Next oFile
    End If
 
    WordApp.Quit
 
    MsgBox "The Find and Replace has been completed. Stay Awesome!"
 
    Set oFSO = Nothing
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing
    Set WordApp = Nothing
    Set WordDocument = Nothing
  
    Exit Sub
  
LeverageLean:
    MsgBox (Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Don't hesitate to email me: brentschneider@leveragelean.com")
    
End Sub
'Stay Awesome`
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please take time to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75016985/edit) your question accordingly. You may also find it helpful to review the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.bookmark) on bookmarks.

Comment: «im unable to incorporate Bookmarks and ScreenTips», Bookmarks and ScreenTips where? The fact that a range in Word is bookmarked makes to difference for the purposes of your code. If you're referring to bookmark names, Find/Replace cannot edit those - you would need to actually delete & recreate the bookmarks. Likewise, ScreenTips typically apply to hyperlinks and Find/Replace cannot edit hyperlink ScreenTips - you would have to edit the hyperlinks.

Comment: If you're referring to Bookmarks and ScreenTips in Excel, you would need to use code that copies the cells to the clipboard instead of just looking at the cell's values and use Find/Replace to paste that content into Word (i.e. ^c as the replacement expression), then deal with the fact you'll have a document full of table cells...

Comment: I appreciate all the feed back and in the process of rewording my question. Ive been stuck on this for at least a month  smh

Comment: I have a Dictionary of over 25000 words structured in Excel. Column A has the Term and Column B had the definition. Im looking to use the Terms in Column A to find the Term in a Word document.... Once the word is found I would like to have the ScreenTip shows when hovering over specific words.

Comment: Im still learning VBA and not sure if another option would work better. The point is to make my reading easier with hover text for words i may not know.

Comment: You would need to turn the found word in Word into a hyperlink and add the definition to that as a Screen Tip.